# How should I iterate through and present several pictures from a local folder?

Tags: python, psychopy

I'm writing an experiment in Psychopy Coder on Windows, Python 3.7.

I would like to present pictures from a local folder in a randomized order to the participant, basically iterating through that folder.

The problem is that because I have many pictures, I wouldn't like to create an ImageStim for every single pic. Also, the pics are in the same folder but with different filenames.

So how should I do this? Could somebody explain this to me please?

Comment: could you paste your code in here ?

Answer (score 1):

You could get a list of all the file names in your directory (see here: [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)). Then you could shuffle that list https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.shuffle . And then you could have a function that would loop through each of the images in that list one at a time. Something like `for i in myimageList: ... visual.ImageStim(...image=i...) ...` My ellipses mean that there are alot more specifics to add. As @ASHu2 suggests, if you give people some example code they may be able to suggest some fixes.

Comment: I used glob.glob and the for loop. It worked, thank you! :)